# display each value of ng-repeat in individual pages

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am working on angularjs application. I have a written angular controller and a service call,the results returned is a list of values. I want to display each value while iterating in each webpage instead of showing the list of values in a single webpage as shown in the fiddle demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/csq6sh9j/11/)

sample js code:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('MyDataController', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.values = [1, 2,3];
    $scope.$watch('myValue', function (newValue, oldValue) {
        if (newValue !== oldValue) {
             return $http.get('../myUrl/'+newValue+'/').then(function(response){
                  // $scope.values = response.data;      
                 $scope.values = [ 1, 2, 3 ];
             });
        }
    });
}]);
```

How to display each individual value returned by `ng-repeat="myData in values"` in individual webpages.Any inputs?

Comment: What do you mean "in individual webpages"? Opening separate tabs? Showing multiple webpages in your tab in iframes? Showing the data full screen, but all in the one actual page?

Comment: showing multiple pages in the same tab. Like for the demo https://jsfiddle.net/csq6sh9j/11/ , i want to show the result "show this value in page1" in webpage 1 and "show this value in page2" in page2 and "show this value in page3" in page3.@GregL

Comment: It's still not clear what you mean by "in webpage 1". Can you mock up what you want the UI to look like?

Answer (score 0):

Does this works?

```
var data = response.data
for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
    $scope.value.push(data[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use $routeParams to pass the value with routes.